# When include Windows.h causes the error A is not a member of B

Tags: c++, include

The following code are my include files:

[image: Include files]

However, I find that when I use `#include <Windows.h>`, the project can not compile, it will come with an error:

```
"LoadImageA": is not a member of "ImageData"
```

On this line:

```
im.LoadImage("bg.png");
```

However, if I do not use #include `, everything works fine. Can any one help me?

Comment: I cannot include <mmsystem.h> as well......QAQ

Comment: Is the LoadImageA in ImageData in a namespace? If it is, are you saying "using namespace ImageData"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with the Win32 API, and affects any symbols that have the same name as Win32 API functions that support `TCHAR` data.

In this case, `Windows.h` includes `winuser.h`, which defines the Win32 API `LoadImage()` function as follows:

```
WINUSERAPI
HANDLE
WINAPI
LoadImageA(
    __in_opt HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in LPCSTR name,
    __in UINT type,
    __in int cx,
    __in int cy,
    __in UINT fuLoad);
WINUSERAPI
HANDLE
WINAPI
LoadImageW(
    __in_opt HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in LPCWSTR name,
    __in UINT type,
    __in int cx,
    __in int cy,
    __in UINT fuLoad);
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadImage  LoadImageW
#else
#define LoadImage  LoadImageA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

The `#define` statements are what is causing your problem.  A `#define` is global in scope, and doesn't respect file boundaries, namespaces, class definitions, etc.  It is just a straight text replacement.  So, while your code is calling this:

```
im.LoadImage("bg.png");
```

The preprocessor changes it to the following, which is what the compiler sees:

```
im.LoadImageA("bg.png");
```

Or:

```
im.LoadImageW("bg.png");
```

Depending on whether you are compiling your project for MBCS or Unicode (in this case, you are using MBCS).

If Microsoft would be nicer to C++ developers, the Win32 API headers would use inline functions instead of C macros, eg:

```
WINUSERAPI
HANDLE
WINAPI
LoadImageA(
    __in_opt HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in LPCSTR name,
    __in UINT type,
    __in int cx,
    __in int cy,
    __in UINT fuLoad);
WINUSERAPI
HANDLE
WINAPI
LoadImageW(
    __in_opt HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in LPCWSTR name,
    __in UINT type,
    __in int cx,
    __in int cy,
    __in UINT fuLoad);

#ifdef __cplusplus
inline HANDLE LoadImage(
    __in_opt HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in LPCTSTR name,
    __in UINT type,
    __in int cx,
    __in int cy,
    __in UINT fuLoad)
{
  #ifdef UNICODE
  return LoadImageW(hInst, name, type, cx, cy, fuLoad);
  #else
  return LoadImageA(hInst, name, type, cx, cy, fuLoad);
  #endif // !UNICODE
}
#else
  #ifdef UNICODE
  #define LoadImage  LoadImageW
  #else
  #define LoadImage  LoadImageA
  #endif // !UNICODE
#endif // !C++
```

That would allow proper scoping and overloading of any names repeated across libraries, classes, etc.  But alas, Microsoft seems unwilling to do that after all these years :(  The Win32 API is primarily designed for C and other C-compatible languages, it provides very little provisions for C++ (not counting things like GDI+, COM, etc).

In any case, for your situation, the simplest solution is to either:

1. rename the `ImageData.LoadImage()` method to a more unique name.
2. use an `#undef LoadImage` statement (assuming you don't need to use the actual Win32 API `LoadImage()` function anywhere else in your source file):

   ```
   #undef LoadImage
   im.LoadImage("bg.png");
   ```

   Or, if you want to be a little more restrictive:

   ```
   #ifdef _WINUSER_
   #undef LoadImage
   #endif

   im.LoadImage("bg.png");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

LoadImage is a macro inside `Windows.h`. It will rewrite any and all occurences of that text to LoadImageW or LoadImageA. Hence your problems. You need to choose different name for your stuff or `#undef` it temporarily.